# Adding variable write_rich_string format properties to a text with Python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, richtext

I want to generate an Excel file with several strings across the cells, and mark some parts of each string with a set of colors.

This is an example if I just wanted to mark a fixed part of a single text:

```
import xlsxwriter

outfile  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet    = outfile.add_worksheet()
bold_red = outfile.add_format({'bold': True,'font_color':'red', 'underline': True})

sheet.write_rich_string(0,0,"This text in black, ",bold_red,"this one in red & bold, ","and this -probably- in other color")

outfile.close()
```

The result is an Excel file with a cell this text in "A1":

[image]

I tried passing a variable input to `write_rich_string`, but the content of `bold_red` is `xlsxwriter.format.Format` and cannot concatenate with strings.

This is how it looks without the colors:

[image: This is how it looks without the colors]

This is the expected output:

[image: Variable coloring, depending on outside variables]

Comment: What output do you want? Can you add an example.

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara . Have just added an example in the question. I would get the info for starting and ending parts, as well as from colors, from an outside file.

Comment: @jmcnamara , I have included in the question the way I have solved so far, without the colors. Thanks!

Comment: There are some examples in the docs ([here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string) and [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html#ex-rich-strings)) that show how to add multiple colour formats to a rich string. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks @jmcnamara !!! Will post in the answer the specific portion I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string) by @jmcnamara I found the answer:

"If you have formats and segments in a list you can add them like this, using the standard Python list unpacking syntax:"

```
segments = ['This is ', bold, 'bold', ' and this is ', blue, 'blue']
worksheet.write_rich_string('A9', *segments)
```

So for each "Text" in my dataframe, will get its pattern for coloring from a external key.
Then form a list with pieces of text and formats embedded.
Finally pass this list as a parameter to `write_rich_string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Write the sentence with a highlighted portion
sentence = "This is an example sentence with a highlighted portion."

# Identify the position of the highlighted portion
start = sentence.find("highlighted")
end = start + len("highlighted")

# Concatenate the formatted strings
formatted_sentence = (
    sentence[:start], normal_format,
    sentence[start:end], highlight_format,
    sentence[end:], normal_format
)

# Write the sentence to the worksheet
worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', *formatted_sentence)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).